# Does the US officially acknowledge that Iran diverted a flight from Dubai to Kyrgyzstan in 2010?

Tags: united-states, iran, transportation

Iran [and Kyrgyzstan](https://www.rferl.org/a/Kyrgyzstan_Confirms_Iran_Intercepted_Plane_Arrested_Two_Passengers/1967264.html) have claimed that a flight from Abu Dhabi to Bishkek was forced to land in Iran in 2010, leading to the arrest of [Abdolmalek Rigi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrest_of_Abdolmalek_Rigi#Arrest_operation), who was later executed.

Interestingly, US intelligence sources [claim](https://foreignpolicy.com/articles/2012/01/13/false_flag) however that Rigi was not captured on that flight but that he was handed over to Iran by Pakistan (with US/Obama approval). It's unclear to me though whether the US even acknowledges that that flight was diverted and forced to land in Iran. Are there any US statements on the matter of the flight?

Answer (score 1):

No, there seem to be no US government statements directly addressing the supposed landing of a flight from Abu Dhabi to Bishkek.

I should note that that there are a number of theories regarding his arrest, as reported by [PBS' Frontline Tehran Bureau](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/tehranbureau/2010/02/was-rigis-arrest-by-iran-staged.html):

> Some Iranian sources, such as the Tabnak news agency, said he was "arrested abroad," offering nothing more specific. By contrast, Iran's English-language Press TV reported that he was captured on a flight from Dubai to Kyrgyzstan. And according to the AP, lawmaker Mohammad Dehghan told the official IRNA news agency that Rigi was "flying over the Persian Gulf en route from Pakistan to an unidentified Arab country when his plane was ordered to land inside Iran."
>
> After that first wave of reports, the Tehran-based news analysis site Iran Diplomacy, run by Iran's former reformist foreign minister Kamal Kharazi, offered still a different version of events. According to Iran Diplomacy, Rigi was arrested with the help of Pakistani intelligence officials, who took action after "consulting" with the United States. Of particular note, the site claims that Rigi was arrested while "he was in hospital."

[The PBS article](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/tehranbureau/2010/02/was-rigis-arrest-by-iran-staged.html) goes on to cast doubt about whether any non-Iranian plane was forced to land at all:

> It is entirely plausible that the Iranians, desperate to show that their intelligence agency has both the capacity to find its targets wherever they may be and the power to force foreign planes to land in its territory, asked the help of the Pakistanis in staging the entire incident. It is very possible that the Pakistan government now sees Jundollah as a liability, and has decided to remove the organization from its soil. This makes much more sense than the version of the capture that involves forcing Rigi's aircraft to land in Iran. If the operation was not staged, there would have been a huge outcry from the foreign nation where the plane is owned. However, not a sound has been heard from any other country about a forced landing. It appears quite possible that if any plane was involved, it was an Iranian one.

The only official US government statement I have found following the arrest is the following report [by NPR](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=124332362&t=1627587880525):

> Asked about Rigi's confession, a spokesperson for the CIA said claims coming out of Iran on this are nonsense.